# Android Virtual Device not running

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, windows-10

my avd is not running on eclipse. sometimes it says, haxm is not installed. sometimes just a black screen appears and nothing happens. why is this happening? i tried to reinstall but nothing happened. but it was working few days ago and suddenly this is happening. i cant run my apps on emulator. how to fix this?? i am using a windows 10 tech preview 64 bit. i have tried to run eclipse on my laptop windows 7 64 bit with different version, same problem. so there must be some technical problem that i dont know, pls help.....

Answer (score 3):

HAXM, the Intel Android Virtualization Technology is incompatible with Hyper-V. Turn off Hyper-V and give it a go again. Hyper-V will often be installed if you have installed Visual Studio with Windows Phone tools.  Or maybe Hyper-V is just turned on somehow?

Or from an admin command prompt run the following. Note to get an admin cmd prompt, right-mouse the windows icon, click Command Prompt (Admin ).

To turn off Hyper-V run this: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off and then reboot

To turn Hyper-V back on, run this: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto And then reboot

You can turn off Hyper-V in the services menu (type "Services" in the Search thingy), and also use the Services menu to turn it back on. Even though it may not be necessary I still reboot after doing it this way.

Blog post on this here - Blog post on this here - http://www.devfish.net/post/2015/08/18/error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration-android-on-windows.aspx

Healy in Tampa

Answer (score 1):

Android emulators are not super reliable. Can you try using genymotion (http://www.genymotion.com/). It is free for personal use and it is super fast.

Comment: What is this? A suggestion? Or solution?

Comment: Yes, it is a solution basis my experience. I am new around here.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android SDK Manager from Eclipse tab "Window", check the box at the very bottom in the Extra folder that says "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" and click Install package. I think you are using an emulator with VM Acceleration.

Comment: i tried that already, in fact recently i downloaded and installed the updated version of haxm but it didn't work.